# Php long script with client side callback

Tags: javascript, php, pdf

I'm have a very long process in a php script (generate a huge pdf).
I have a button in my HTML page that launches the php script and I'd like to show a kind of progress bar or at least an animated gif and when the php script is over, display the generated pdf.

The generation of the pdf may last 15 minutes so the php engine exits in timeout and the browser too.

I there a way to declare a kind of client-side callback that would be invoked as soon as the server side process is over ?

Thanks for your replies

**Edit :**

Thanks for your replies :)
If I well understand, I must launch the process on server-side and "detach" my client i.e do not wait untill the process is over. Instead, my client should periodically check the progression of server-side process. Right ?

If so, I may use the following scenario :

- The client sends an ajax request to the server. The server launches
  the process and returns a guid to the client. This guid identifies
  the job.
- The client periodically checks the progression of the job
  via an Ajax request, from its guid.
- Once the job is over, the client    can issue a last Ajax query to
  download the PDF

That means that the server must save the generated PDF on its disk and wait for the final Ajax request to send the file and delete it, right ?

Comment: you really should push this in to the background, and let the client know when its done say by email.

Answer (score 0):

For something as long as 15 minutes, I wouldn't even use web sockets for this.  15 minutes is a *long* time and there's really no telling what the user is going to be doing in the meantime.  A disconnected notification process is probably going to be more reliable in this case.

Consider something like:

1. User initiates process, whereby a record is stored in the database "queueing" the process to take place.
2. User is immediately presented with a page indicating that the process has been queued and that they can continue to use the application.
3. A separate application which runs periodically (every minute?  every few minutes?) checks for "queued" processes in the database, updates their status to "in-progress" (so subsequent runs don't also pick up the same records), and processes them.
4. As each process completes, it's either removed from the database or updated to a "completed" status.
5. The user is otherwise notified that the process is complete.

This final notification can be done a number of ways.  An email can be sent to the user, for example.  Or consider a user experience similar to the Facebook notification bar.  Each page in the website can check for "completed" processes when the page loads and present a "notification" in the UI which directs the user to the result of the process.  If users spend a lot of time on any given page then *this* would be a good place to use web sockets or long polling via JavaScript to keep checking for completed processes.

The main thing is to separate the user interface from the long-running process.  Web applications by design aren't suited for processes which run for that long.  By separating the concerns the web application can focus just on the user interface and the command-line application can focus on the processing.  (As an added bonus, this would prevent users from over-loading the server with too many concurrent processes.  The command-line application can just run one record at a time, so too many concurrent processes just slows down the response, not the server.)

Answer (score 0):

as @David said, but no one has covered the progress bar, the implantation of this depends on what you know ( you being the application creating the pdf ).

1. Do you know the size of the pdf when complete.
2. Do you know how long
       it will take to generate.
3. Do you have code where you can hook into
       to update the progress.

The application needs a way to know when to update the completed percentage, and by how much. If you can do that then you can either store the progress in the database with the script that crates the PDF and read it on a user facing page, or store it in a file, etc..

jQuery UI progress bar is easy to use, but you will have to know what percentage is done to be able to tell the end user.

After that it is a pretty simple matter of using ajax (jquery $.post ) and a file, that's how i do it. I just wright a simple text file with a number representing the completion percent.  Load it via ajax and feed it to the jquery ui progress widget.